# openAI api - is it possible save chat state \history by the api (without resending it)?

Tags: node.js, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I want to develop a chat app using `gpt-3.5-turbo`.  I'm using NodeJS.

I would like it to save the state of the conversation with the user, so I won't have to send the whole conversation and the priming each time.

What I want to accomplish is very similar to what chatbot ui is doing today. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention what languages you know how to program in, so I'll answer using Swift as an example, but something similar should be possible on many different Platforms.

One approach would be to save your questions and responses to Core Data, SQLite or a Realm DB. [Persistent Storage]. You not only have a record of questions and responses, but can later access these records for follow up questions.

Take a look at

[GitHub Link](https://github.com/Yoddikko/yoddChatGPT)

for an example of an app does this (restores the conversation upon relaunch).

Good luck!

Comment: good point. I added it  to original question

Comment: Looks good. Consider adding the tag or tags for nodejs and javascript so that those people, who can help you further, have a better chance of seeing the question. Your goal here should be to show the question to as many people who might know the answer as possible.